# Cant define a hash in the params, using field_for and rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes, filterrific

I am trying to submit 2 values to a rails scope. I need the radius (submitted by a range tag) and the postcode.

I have a fields_for tag in a form (in haml):

```
      =f.fields_for :postcode do |postcode_fields|
        =postcode_fields.text_field(:postcode_d,placeholder: "HQ Location")
        =postcode_fields.range_field(:max_range, in: 1..100)
```

Scope:

```
scope :postcode, lambda {|input|
return nil  if input.blank?

terms = Scotland.near(input[0], input[1])

where(
terms.map { |term|
  " charity_id = ?"
}.join(' OR '),
*terms.map {|e|(e.charity_id)}.flatten
)
}
```

Controller:

```
    def scotland_params
      params.require(:scotland).permit!(:charity_number, :charity_name, :registered_date, :known_as, :charity_status, postcode: [:postcode_d,:max_range] , :constitutional_form)
    end
```

The problem seems to be in my definition of postcode. I have tried a variety of ways to define the postcode hash, none of which have worked. For the one i have use here the error is

```
SyntaxError 

    (/Users/peterkentish/Documents/UNIVERSITY/SecondYear/Semester2/SoftwareHut/project/app/controllers/scotlands_controller.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected =>
..., :charity_status, postcode: =>[:postcode_d, :max_range] , :...
...                               ^
/Users/peterkentish/Documents/UNIVERSITY/SecondYear/Semester2/SoftwareHut/project/app/controllers/scotlands_controller.rb:46: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
...: =>[:postcode_d, :max_range] , :constitutional_form, :previ...
...                               ^):
```

TL;DR
How do i pass nested attributes in rails 5?

EDIT:

params hash (i think):

```
@scotlands = Scotland.all
@filterrific = initialize_filterrific(Scotland, params[:filterrific]) or return
 @scotlands = @filterrific.find.page(params[:scotlands])
@scotlands = @scotlands.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)

respond_to do |format|
format.html
format.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this, there is a bug in the gem filterrific:

https://github.com/jhund/filterrific/pull/116

Thanks to those who helped

Answer (score 1):

The real question is why everbody goes totally bonkers when it comes to writing strong params and crams the whole definition into a single line.

Unreadable code is how you get errors.

```
def scotland_params
  params.require(:scotland).permit(
    :charity_number, :charity_name, :registered_date, 
    :known_as, :charity_status, :constitutional_form,
    postcode_attributes: [:postcode_d, :max_range]
  )
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have tried this and i get: ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameter: postcode):

Comment: Hmm try it as `postcode: [:postcode_d, :max_range]` instead of `postcode_attributes`

Comment: Same problem unfortunately, ive been stuck on this for ages so thanks again. Some places have said it should be `:postcode => [:postcode_d, :max_range]`, but this also does not work

Comment: Can you add the params hash to the question?

Comment: Added, i think thats what you meant?

Comment: No - look at the logs or the output in console where you are running `rails server` - you should see a hash of the incoming parameters.

Comment: `Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "filterrific"=>
  {"charity_number"=>"",
   "most_recent_year_income_g"=>"",
   "most_recent_year_income_l"=>"",
   "most_recent_year_expenditure_g"=>"",
   "most_recent_year_expenditure_l"=>"",
   "purposes"=>"",
   "beneficiaries"=>"",
   "postcode"=>{"postcode_d"=>"EH47 8BY", "max_range"=>"51"},
   "main_operating_location"=>""},
 "commit"=>"Apply Filters"}`

Comment: thats really strange - according to the docs fields_for should give `postcode_attributes`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for

Comment: One thing is that you're using `.permit!` instead of `.permit`. `.permit!` allows any keys.

Comment: I have tried `.permit` also.. When i have this: 

`params.require(:scotland).permit(:charity_number, :charity_name, 
:registered_date,         
:known_as, :charity_status ,
 :constitutional_form, 
postcode_attributes: [:postcode_d, :max_range] ,
:regulatory_type)`

I get the error:
`SyntaxError (/Users/peterkentish/Documents/UNIVERSITY/SecondYear/Semester2/SoftwareHut/project/app/controllers/scotlands_controller.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>):`
@max

Comment: You need to put ´postcode_attributes´ last as its a keyword argument, the others are positional arguments.

Comment: You can do `foo('bar', baz: 'woo')` but not `foo(baz: 'woo', 'bar' )`

Comment: That cleared up that error, still have `found unpermitted parameter: postcode`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'd want to either wrap `:postcode => [:postcode_d, :max_range]` in `{...}` or move `:postcode => [:postcode_d, :max_range]` to the end of the `permit!` argument list.

The `SyntaxError` is Ruby, when interpreting your code, expecting nothing after the `:postcode` hash since there are no explicit `{...}`.